# Creating and Editing Excel Chart

Tags: vb.net, excel, charts, vba

I am trying to create a data analysis program using vb.net. The data is in an excel file. The X Values are in A col from A2, Y Values are in B col from B2.

I am able to generate a chart from this data.

How do I format the chart:

1. Add Title
2. Change the line color in the chart to any specified color
3. Add a trend line (polynomial)
4. Modify the color of the trend line
5. Add another series(Data Set plot) to the chart
6. Edit the Series names
7. X,Y Labels

Any other formatting tips are appreciated.

Sorry for my ambiguous question. So what am trying to do is to automate excel to create some charts using vb.net.

I am not sure how to implement this since I am new to vb.net. I am able to create a micro in excel which does all the functions. But I am not sure how to code this in vb.net.

Is there a way to convert this vba excel micro to vb.net?

```
Sub Macro2()
  '
  ' Macro2 Macro
  '

  '
   Range("B1:B14").Select
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
   ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
   ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$B$1:$B$14")
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
   With Selection.Format.Line
       .Visible = msoTrue
       .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
       .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
       .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
   End With
   With Selection.Format.Line
       .Visible = msoTrue
       .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
       .Transparency = 0
   End With
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines.Add
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1).Select
   With Selection
       .Type = xlPolynomial
       .Order = 2
   End With
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could try reading the documentation.

Comment: sounds like your question is doomed because it is too broad and no one will answer it on SO. Sorry

Comment: I think you right click the chart and then there should be dialogs that allow you to set all these options...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you. I have found the solution to these problems. Please see my other post
[How to set the XValues of a series in excel using vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329726/how-to-set-the-xvalues-of-a-series-in-excel-using-vb-net)

The example shows how to create a chart and most of the formatting methods. There is one minor error in the code which has been answered by TnTinMn in the post.